# Changed from english to arabic, however some language system text is still in arabic

Tags: 16.04, language-support, arabic

I study arabic, so I thought it would be fun to change the system language to arabic on my ubuntu 16.04. However noticed that it wasn't that fun and since I'm still quite new to the language I changed it back to english. However, there are still some things which kept the arabic language. The login window, and system windows text and buttons.  How can I change these back?

Comment: How did you change languages ? Have you logged out and back in ? rebooted ?